# How to configure static routing when there are two routers between the source and destination network?

Tags: routing, layer3

How can i perform static routing from router A to reach 192.168.1.0/30 network in the below diagram(please don't ask why do i need two routers between them).
All the example of static routing i have found shown,how to perform static routing from Router B to reach 192.168.1.0/30 network.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *static route* is added to the routing table of a certain device. It needs to be added on all relevant routers. Alternatively, a routing protocol can be used to make the routers exchange their routing table information.

In your diagram, routers A and B require a (static) route to the subnet behind router C, and router C requires a route back to A.

If there are any more networks behind any of the routers, these need to be configured on the non-local routers as well.

Usually, there's a default route pointing in some direction, so you wouldn't really require specific routes that point in the same direction.

Answer (score 2):

Every router in the path makes its own routing decision, so you need to configure a static route on every router.  The last-hop router already has an entry for the local subnet, so a static route is not needed there.

Don't forget to configure routes from the destination back to the source.